# bounded operator sends bounded set to bounded set

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

How it follows from the title, the (supposet to be easy) exercise is to show that
$$\begin{Vmatrix} Tx\end{Vmatrix} \leq C \begin{Vmatrix} x\end{Vmatrix}\iff T\text{ sends bounded set to bounded set}$$ (we are talking about linear operator between normed spaces).

Let $$A: = \{ y: \begin{Vmatrix} x - y\end{Vmatrix} \leq C_x \}$$ then $$ \begin{Vmatrix} Tx + Ty\end{Vmatrix} \leq \begin{Vmatrix} Tx\end{Vmatrix} + \begin{Vmatrix} Ty \end{Vmatrix} \leq C_1 \begin{Vmatrix} x \end{Vmatrix} + C_2 \begin{Vmatrix}  y\end{Vmatrix}$$ so the image  of $A$ is bounded. 
  Now I have a difficultes with the converse, it's the matter of notation, I'm sure it se more than easy using right notation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose a linear operator $T\colon X\longrightarrow Y$ maps bounded sets in $X$ into bounded sets in $Y$. WLOG, choose any bounded sets that is centred at zero. This means that for any fixed $R>0$, there exists a constant $M_R>0$ such that $\|x\|\le R\implies \|Tx\|\le M_R$. We now take any nonzero $y\in X$ and set
$$ x=R\dfrac{y}{\|y\|} \implies \|x\| = R. $$
Thus,
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{R}{\|y\|}\|Ty\| = \left\|T\left(\dfrac{R}{\|y\|}y\right)\right\| = \|Tx\| & \le M_R.\\
\implies \|Ty\| & \le \dfrac{M_R}{R}\|y\|.
\end{align*}
where we crucially used the linearity of $T$. Rearranging and taking supremum over all $y$ of norm 1 shows that $T$ is bounded.

Comment: Yeah, right, I thought about bounded sets not necesserely into a ball centred in zero.

Comment: You were right there, but I can always rescale the set to be centred at zero :pI remembered getting points off from my professor because I forgot to mention this when I wrote my solution last time!

Comment: And I forgot that we can always use the ball centred in zero when I wrote my question here (generally, asking such kind of questions is quite ashamed ;d)

Comment: @Vladislav Don't be, in fact you should be proud of yourself; it takes a lot of courage to ask any questions in MSE!

Comment: If $Tx$ is bounded when $x$ varies in a set $A$, then should$ A $also be bounded? If $T$ is non zero

Comment: @MadhanKumar Only if $T$ is a bounded operator.

Comment: @CheeHan Why do we take supremum over all y of norm equal to exactly 1? Why is the value 1 important?

Comment: @НикитаВасильев That comes from the homogeneity of norm. The norm of a bounded linear operator $T$ is defined as $\displaystyle\|T\| = \sup_{x\in\mathrm{dom}(T), x\neq 0} \dfrac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|} = \sup_{x\in\mathrm{dom}(T), \|x\| = 1} \|Tx\|$.

Comment: Ah, damn. I haven't been introduced to the norm of operator yet. :(

Comment: @CheeHan  can u plz elaborate in your explaination where u take sup over all y of norm 1?bcz i can see only rearranging !